# Mudar a cor de uma palavra em um textarea ainda em edição

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Como faço para que toda vez que o navegador achar uma "palavra reservada" no `textarea`, ele automaticamente mude a cor dela.

Eu quero saber para fazer um destaque de sintaxe.

Comment: Até ao que sei não é possível dar estilo a partes de uma `<textarea>`. A solução mais comum é utilizar uma `<div>` com o atributo `contenteditable="true"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível alterar partes do texto de um `textarea` (bem como de um `input`). Você consegue aplicar estilos (cor, fundo, tipo de fonte, tamanho etc.) ao texto por inteiro ou ao elemento, e não por partes dele. Isso porque o `textarea` não renderiza tags HTML, e seu conteúdo é tratado como texto puro.

O que você pode fazer é usar plugins [WYSIWYG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) que substitui o `textarea` por uma `div` editável e aplicar *listeners* que irão detectar as *palavras reservadas* no texto e aplicar a cor desejada somente nestas palavras (trabalho um pouco complicado, diga-se de passagem). Para isso você terá que pesquisar a forma que o JavaScript trata as instâncias do plugin e fazer uma programação à parte.

Alguns plugins WYSIWYG disponíveis, dentre outros, são o [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) e o [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor).

Answer (score 2):

Apenas como complemento à resposta do @DvD, mostro um exemplo muito simplista (e com algumas falhas) de como poderia implementar mudanças de cor de determinadas palavras utilizando `<div>` com `contenteditable=true`:

```js
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

//palavras que se pretende substituir e a classe com o estilo para essas palavras
const sintaxe = [
  {
    palavra:"int",
    classe:"tipo"
  },
  {
    palavra:"if",
    classe:"base"
  }
];


$("#editor").on("keyup", function(){ //aplicar a troca para cada tecla digitada
  let cnt = $("#editor").html();

  for (s of sintaxe){ //para cada palavra aplicar a substituição no editor
    //fazer o troca da palavra por um span com mesma palavra e a classe certa
    cnt=cnt.replace(s.palavra+" ", `<span class="${s.classe}">${s.palavra}</span> `);
  }
  
  $("#editor").html(cnt); //colocar o texto substituido de volta

  //colocar o cursor no fim de novo
  placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById("editor"));
});
```

```css
#editor {
  border:1px solid orange;
}

.tipo {
  color:darkBlue;
}

.base {
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Escreva algum texto como int x; if(x==10) {
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

A função de colocação do cursor no fim veio de uma [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/6087092) e é necessário para que e exemplo funcione corretamente, uma vez que quando há uma substituição do html do `<div>` por javascript o cursor volta ao inicio.